Magento 2 product search by keyword on the backend is returning a timeout
When I try to search for a product by keyword, it times out and shows a 524 error. When I checked the debug log, it showed a warning like the one below.
Did not write session for ID 9gem1h273t5rm8fis0ircsggjp: another process took the lock. /backendadmin/mui/index/render/key/f0165d32f1ac1cb7322ca4d6a28c7e3f03044d4146424d27e19c87cd8ae5f9a0/?namespace=product_listing&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&search=monitor&keywordUpdated=true&sorting%5Bfield%5D=name&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true

If anyone has an idea about this problem, please respond. Thanks in advance.

try use this link to solve your issue.
https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/issues/56
the change is in app/etc/env.php
in redis
